# Why was my question about Stockfish levels off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How do Stockfish 13 Levels (Lichess) work?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35312/how-do-stockfish-13-levels-lichess-work)

> This question does not appear to be about chess within the scope defined in the help center.

So, what does the help center say?

> Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome.

I don't feel very welcome at all. Other questions about *how an engine works*, not just using the program, were not considered off-topic:

- [Do Stockfish and the tablebase work together or independently?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/do-stockfish-and-the-tablebase-work-together-or-independently?rq=1)
- [Lichess' Stockfish's tuning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/lichess-stockfishs-tuning?rq=1)
- [Stockfish blunders away a piece](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/stockfish-blunders-away-a-piece?rq=1)
- [How does Stockfish ensure an incremental change made is beneficial?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23620/how-does-stockfish-ensure-an-incremental-change-made-is-beneficial?rq=1)
- [Did AlphaZero also have to learn that each piece has a value?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35213/did-alphazero-also-have-to-learn-that-each-piece-has-a-value)
- etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original question read (to me) like a general user complaint about how this was working on Lichess. Apologies for my misunderstanding and now that you have made it clear that you primary interest is a chess programming one I have reopened.